# Vertically Scrolling a <DIV>

Tags: css, ajax, html

I have a few nested  and I want to allow my deepest  to scroll vertically.

in CSS I have tried adding:

```
overflow-x: hidden; /* horizontal */
overflow-y: auto;  /* vertical */
```

to the class I am assigning to the  but that does not seem to do it. Changing overflow-y: yes; does not work either.

How does one accomplish this. I want this  to scroll because it gets populated with MySQL data where the other div's just present selectable criteria to create the query and run it.

thoughts are appreciated.

Example:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="slidingDivKeynotePresentations">
        <!-- content here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
#content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 21%;
    margin: 26% 31% 1% 21%; /* Cater for Mac IE5 */
    /*\*/ margin: 0; /* Put back for all the rest */
    /*\*/ overflow: auto; /* no need for Mac IE5 to see this */
    overflow-x: hidden; /* horizontal */
    overflow-y: yes;  /* vertical */
}

#slidingDivKeynotePresentations {
    display: none;
    height: 600px;
    width: 600px;
    background-image: url('images/transwhite.png');
    border: 1px solid #3F4933;
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px; 
    left: 290px; /*Set left value to WidthOfFrameDiv*/
    padding: 12px;
    overflow-x: hidden; /* horizontal */
    overflow-y: auto;  /* vertical */
 }
```

Comment: "yes" is not a valid value for the `overflow` property. (http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_overflow.asp) Just thought I'd mention.

Comment: @victor - that was a typo from my pasting in the code.

Comment: I don't think you really need to hack for Mac IE5 anymore.  Save yourself the headache, as Microsoft doesn't even support it anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UgaBb/2/) with it working: Just replace `position: fixed` with `position: relative;` in the inner div.  I took away all of the overflow-x and -y, and simply put overflow: auto on the containing div. And I also moved the border to the outer div so it wouldn't get cut off at the bottom. But I think all you *need* to do is switch the fixed with relative.

To take away the horizontal scrollbar, simply make the width of the inner div the same or smaller then the width of the outer div.  Especially since CSS3 overflow-x and -y is not widely available yet.

Comment: @JMC Creative - JSFiddle is interesting. I removed all overflow-x and overflow-y and I replaced with position: relative on the inner div (slidingKeyNotePresentations) and that doesn't scroll, it moves the whole dive to a new position on the page. Farther to the right and down more.

Comment: Right.  Probably 100px from the left and 290px from the top  :)  You'll then need to adjust the margin and top/left position settings.  I would suggest setting the position: relative, taking out all of the top/left and margin settings and then re-adding as necessary.

Comment: @JMC Creative - OK, very close now! And I am actually understanding this which is great. I don't feel like I know enough CSS.I guess I need to stick to C++. I have scrolling now. But I have horizontal scrolling and I don't want that. So I made my outer div 601px and my inner 599px and it still scrolls. I have a table inside the inner div and that is 550px but it still scrolls. What am I missing? Also, I changed my DocType to get scrolling to work away from xhtml.

Comment: @JMC Creative - More on the horizontal scrolling. I worked backwards starting with my table out and made sure that the div was list 1px bigger taking into account padding left and right. fo for example my table is 590px no padding - The div that contains that is 600px with 12px padding on left and right, so = 624px and the main div that contains all of that is 625px. I still have horizontal scrolling.. What don't I understand still?

Comment: Your best bet may be to take out all margins and padding on the inner div. Also I would NOT specify a width for the inner div. When calculating the inner width, don't forget to add in the padding of the inner div, as well as it's margins and borders. Also, you have percentages for your outer margins, which may be doing you in... It's difficult to say more without seeing it...

Comment: @JMC Creative - perfect advice. Awesome knowledge you have of CSS

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for the `overflow` property; `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` are not supported by all browsers; they are new in CSS3

- http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_overflow.asp
- http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#overflow

Answer (score 0):

Take out the overflow-y and overflow-x.  You should'nt need to specify overflow-x: hidden, as that is default anyway.  Simply setting overlow: auto; on the #slidingDivKeynotePresentations should do the trick, shouldn't it?  As long as there's a height specified.

Comment: I thought it would too. I removed all overflow-x and overflow-y and simply replaced with overflow: auto on #slidingDivKeynotePresentations and no dice. I even tried overflow: scroll. Which does show a place for a scroll, but it does not work and the content is clearly overflowing! Any more ideas or info that I can provide?